# Comparing scores on different dimensions in factor models

Tags: factor-analysis, item-response-theory, philosophical

So I'm currently conducting some research where I'm using item response theory (IRT) to estimate the difficulty of school subjects in Norway. It turns out that a two-dimensional, simple-structure model where social science and natural science subjects load separately provides a much better fit. Now I'm a little unsure of what ways the difficulty of the subjects can actually be compared. I'm also having a hard time actually finding any literature on it.

I feel like there's perhaps a philosophical discussion to be had when comparing item difficulty from two separate, albeit correlated, constructs. Does anyone have any thoughts on this, or perhaps some literature they could point to?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated.  Could you clarify:  what sorts of variables are used as inputs to your factor-analysis models?  What sort of constructs are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you! The grades of students are the observed variables, and so a multi-dimensional model where natural science, language, and social science subjects load separately provides a much better fit and reliable parameter estimation. Therefore, although there are strong correlations between these factors (from .75 to .79), academic achievement is more accurately perceived as a multi-dimensional construct.

Comment: How do you define item difficulty? Maybe you can present, as an edit to the post, some of the model results?